# is there way to modify filter in Angular MatTableDataSource to filter data from the beginning of the searched expression and not included?

Tags: angular-material, angular9

I have the same implementation as this stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3mmmp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

For exemple if i search about "sa" in  input i have two results.
I just want to have the result of the name that starts with "sa" ( one result in this case)
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o84b3.png)

Anyone have an idea how to start filtering from the beginning of the expression using MatTableDatasource ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is found.

in line 91 Replace : **data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.name) !== -1** by **data.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerms.name)**